# How can i use expr function in this case [Linux]

Tags: linux, bash

case1

```
i="text stack"
j="tex"
if [[ $(expr "$i" : "$j") -ne 0 ]];then
echo true
fi
```

case2

```
i="text stack"
j="stac"
if [[ $(expr "$i" : "$j") -ne 0 ]];then
echo true
fi
```

case3

```
i="text stack"
j="ext"
if [[ $(expr "$i" : "$j") -ne 0 ]];then
echo true
fi
```

It works only in case1. How can I make it work (and echo true) in all cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `:` operator for expr is an *anchored* regex, i.e. will only match at the beginning of the string (as if your regex started with a `'^'`).

As you're using bash's `[[` builtin operator, I would write this as:

```
i="text stack"
j="stac"
if [[ "$i" =~ "$j" ]]; then
  echo true
fi
```

`=~` means (from the bash manpage) *... the string to the right of the operator is considered an extended regular expression and matched accordingly (as in regex(3)). The return value is 0 if the string matches the pattern, and 1 otherwise.*

Comment: +1 for: always use internal bash features instead of an external command that does the same thing because it is more expensive to spawn a new process.  However this answer could be improved a bit: use `[[ $i == *$j* ]]` as globs are slightly more efficient than regex.  Unrelated to that, there is no need to quote inside `[[ ]]` since no word-splitting takes place.